# SQL 2000 Reporting Services security

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2000

My report subscriptions became invisible as company has chaned network configuration. The reports still run by schedule but subscription is not maintainable as it is invisible. Is it possible to do anything to fix it besides deleting and recreating all 150 reports?

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that SQL Server 2000 even _had_ reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a couple of years since I've done much with SSRS 2000. (@John Saunders: It was released in about 2003, not with the initial product.)

I'm not sure what the question's goal is: to make the reports visible again or to stop the subscriptions?

If to make the reports visible again:

- Have you tried both the report manager url and the reportserver url?
- The report server url is what the subscriptions use to generate the reports, so it may still be available. This url typically ends with /reportserver/
- What error do you receive, or are there any messages in the logs that let you see what the problem is?
- Can you upgrade Reporting Services to SQL 2005 or SQL 2008?

If the goal is to stop the orphaned subscriptions: These are jobs that the SQL Agent runs. They have messy GUID names, but those link back to the Reporting Services tables:
From [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic254010-150-1.aspx)

```
SELECT
   Schedule.ScheduleID AS SQLAgent_Job_Name,
   Subscriptions.Description AS sub_desc,
   Subscriptions.DeliveryExtension AS sub_delExt,
   [Catalog].Name AS ReportName,
   [Catalog].Path AS ReportPath
FROM       ReportSchedule
INNER JOIN Schedule ON ReportSchedule.ScheduleID = Schedule.ScheduleID
INNER JOIN Subscriptions ON ReportSchedule.SubscriptionID = Subscriptions.SubscriptionID
INNER JOIN [Catalog] ON ReportSchedule.ReportID = [Catalog].ItemID AND Subscriptions.Report_OID = [Catalog].ItemID
```